# Как в unity вращать только один объект из пула?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при спавне объекта он появлялся под неким углом, который постоянно меняется, но не случайный. При создании-уничтожении я делал

```
`for (int I = 0; i  < 50; i++){
transform.position = new Vector3 (i+10, 0,  transform.position.z)
Instantiate(obj [Random.Range (0, obj.GetLength (0))], transform.position, transform.rotation );// появляется случайный объект в такой же позиции, как и раньше, под тем же углом, что и раньше (угол меняется в совсем другом месте)
}`
```

Тут obj [] - массив, в который входят квадрат с прямоугольником. И при вращении квадрата все последующие квадраты появляются под таким же углом, а прямоугольники - нет (так и должно быть). Но как сделать такое же, но из пула? Я убрал строку Instantiate и написал это:

```
GameObject newObject = theObjectPools[objectSelector].GetPooledObject ();// в этом пуле хранятся квадрат и прямоугольник
newObject.transform.position = transform.position; // позиция появления квадрата или прямоугольника
newObject.transform.rotation = transform.rotation; // угол их появления
```

В итоге я могу сделать так, чтобы все появляющиеся объекты спавнились под каким-то углом, но две проблемы:1) все объекты меняют угол, а нужны только квадраты, 2) Quaternion не принимает float (не могу сказать ему, чтобы имел такой же угол, как вон тот квадрат).
Как сделать так, чтобы только квадраты появлялись с нужным углом?

Comment: может есть смысл как-то разделить методы квадрата и прямоугольника (например разный срипт и дёргать нужное). Так же `Quaternion` принимает флоат, просто нужно использовать или `Euler` координаты (там есть опция) или сразу работать с https://habrahabr.ru/post/183908/

Comment: Сделал с костылем. Создал где-то сверху объект, который вращается. И, при создании квадрата (с углом 0) он меняет свой угол на такой же, который у объекта сверху (т.к квадрат создается за полем видимости, то это движение пользователь не видит). Если с производительностью все будет хорошо, то оставлю этот вариант. Но он мне не нравится, так что надеюсь на ответы. А про разделение - была идея сделать типа "если длина объекта равна двум, то делать то-то". Но тут подумал - вращать нужно не весь пул (это плохо!!!), а только объект в нем... А вот как, все-таки не придумал

Comment: я сам пули никогда не юзал:) я всё ручками использовал (просто массивы объектов, в 1 пуле объекты 1 типа).

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня в конкретных точках должен создаваться один из случайных объектов (с условием выше), и расчитывать, может он там появиться или нет для меня будет слишком) хотя возможно

Answer (score 1):

Если объект A является parent'ом объектов B и C, то при вращении A на опр угол все объекты ниже по иерархии будут вращаться вместе с ним. Чтобы этого избежать нужно всем children'ам поставить transform.parent = null, повернуть объект А и после обратно выставить transform.parent = A.

Вы, похоже, вместо изменения поворота объекта в сцене меняете поворот префаба. У префаба стоит выставить нулевой поворот, а потом инстанцировать его

```
var instantiated = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab)
instantiated.rotation = ...
```